# How to retrieve data from Table-Function in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have a Table Function it return a table of (student_id,student_name)

I want to call it and insert the result into another table

I use

```
INSERT INTO STUDENT_TMP SELECT Table(MyDB.fn_getStudent())
```

but i did not get the result
I have got an error :

```
ERROR: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-390, SQLSTATE=42887,
 SQLERRMC=MyDB.AA;SQL131208155041300,DRIVER=3.67.26 
    Error Code: -390
```

Comment: ... `SELECT ** FIELDS from (** Table(MyDB.fn_getStudent())`, I thik there is missing the "FIELDS from ("

Comment: I think I moved the '(' at wrong placees, above

Comment: Which version of DB2, please?

Answer (score 2):

I found the followin exsample on ibm sites:

```
select t1.timeid, t1.storeid, t1.sales
from time, store, table (cvsample.salesfunc(time.timeid, store.storeid)) as t1
where time.timeid = t1.timeid and store.storeid = t1.storeid;
```

notice the syntax: **table (cvsample.salesfunc(time.timeid, store.storeid)) as t1**

so you prob dont need fields and 'as' you still need '*' and the 'FROM'

so

```
INSERT INTO STUDENT_TMP SELECT * FROM Table (MyDB.fn_getStudent())
```

Comment: Usually, table functions need a correlation name (e.g., **as t1**) when referenced. There might be some exceptions, though I haven't seen one.